# opening same form again from button click in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have a button in my dashboard form opening another form called entry, but when entry is minimised and if i click again on the open button in dashboard another window is opening instead of maximising the same minimised form. i am very new to this visual studio 2019 & c#.

```
private void Btngotoentryform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmDataEntry f = new FrmDataEntry();
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's what you told your program to do. Open a **new** form. If you want to maximize your old form, you will need to program that. Save your form as a variable and check if it exists. If it already exists, maximize it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: You'll need to check if `FrmDataEntry` is already open or you need to display this form in dialog mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global instance of the form on which you can perform nullcheck

```
private FrmDataEntry _instance = null;

private void Btngotoentryform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_instance == null)
   {
     _instance = new FrmDataEntry();
     _instance.Show();
   }
   else
   { 
    _instance.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; 
    _instance.Activate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucifer thank you , But now the error message is coming as "cannot implicitly convert type 'MS_Dies.FrmDataEntry' to bool"  ..